# In Lightroom how do I determine what collections an image is in?

Tags: lightroom

I have created several collections, where some images are in more than one collection. Is there a way to show what collections a particular image is in?

I have one small collection where I want to check each image to see if it was also placed in one or more of several much larger collections.

I am using LR 4.4 on a mac. If I can't do this within LR, is there a way to do it with scripting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try right-clicking a picture and find the option "Go to Collection". It should contain the list of collections where that picture is.

Comment: You should put comments under the question using "add comment" link.

Comment: That was something I didn't know about. It gives me a list of collections that the image is in.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto - strictly speaking, yes, it looks like a comment. But it's also THE answer to my question.